# Переклад суфікса -al

Tags: from-english, суфікси

Цікавлять українські відповідники суфікса *-al*.

> суфікс із загальним сенсом “певного типу, стосовний до, що має форму
> чи характер чогось” що зветься через корінь із запозичених слів із
> латинської в англійську (autumnal; natural; pastoral), також
> продуктивний в англійській за латинською моделлю, зазвичай з основами
> латинського походження (accidental; seasonal; tribal).

Шукаю такий відповідник, щоб в результаті з іменника можна було утворити іменник. Це може бути не обов'язково суфікс, але й інша конструкція.

Answer (score 5):

Ви не можете перекладати суфікси окремо. Зовсім не можете. Тому що суфікси — це не те, що перекладачі перекладають окремо. Переклад суфіксів — це не правильний спосіб перекладання слів. Як вже було багаторазово доведено науковцями, переклад окремо суфіксів не дозволить вам перекласти слово. Не кажучи вже про передачу сенсу цілого речення. Переклад суфіксів — це засіб, що не є достатньо кваліфікованим, щоб донести сенс слова, яке перекладається. Суфікси не є регулярним явищем, у тому сенсі, що один і той самий суфікс, застосований до різних слів, може призводити до різних значеннєвих наслідків порівняно з кореневим словом. Розбір слова на окремі його частини має сенс у історично-лінгвістичній перспективі, але такий розбір призводить до розділу слова на частини, сума яких не відповідає слову, яке потрібно перекласти. Навіть розширене тлумачення частин слова, яке залучає крос-лінгвістичні аспекти, які дозволяють розглянути суфікс і його еквіваленти у різних мовах, не дає можливості перекласти слово. Ви цього просто ніколи не зробите. Мова є інструментом, що є достатньо складним, щоб слово не було можливо відтворити з його частин. Навіть професор Тищенко не міг би перекласти будь-яке слово, відділивши і переклавши окремо суфікси від нього. Щоразу, коли ви намагаєтеся перекласти суфікс окремо від слова, десь у світі гірко плаче ховрашок, третій янгол сурмить, велика зірка падає з небес, а руськіє хакери викрадають вашу базу даних. Намагання перекласти суфікс окремо від усього слова викликає душі мертвих перекладачів. Вони постають з мертвих і спостерігають за вашими невдалими спробами перекласти суфікс. Щоразу, коли ви це намагаєтеся зробити, ви віддаєте свою душу Йому, Чиє Ім'я Не Можна Перекласти, бо воно містить іншомовний суфікс. Темр**ява** спускається на того, хто намагатиметься перекласти суфікс `-ness` у слові *dark**ness***. О ні, вони вже йдуть! Ні-і-і-ііі!

---

#### А тепер серйозно.

В англійській мові морфологічно еквівалентні слова можуть належати до різних частин мови. *Metal* цілком може означати як *метал* (іменник), так і *металічний/металевий* (прикметник), причому останні два мають **різне** семантичне значення.

Окрім того, *metal* — це зовсім не те саме, що *met-* + *-al*:

> [***metal***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/metal#Etymology)  From Middle English, a borrowing from Old French *metal*, from Latin *metallum* (“metal, mine, quarry, mineral”), itself a borrowing from Ancient Greek **μέταλλον** (métallon, “mine, quarry, metal”).

> [μέταλλον](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BC%CE%AD%CF%84%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%BD#Etymology) From Pre-Greek because of the presence of -αλλο- (-allo-).

> У свою чергу, *-αλλο-* — знахідний відмінок одними чол.роду від [***άλλος***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%AC%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%82#Greek), що має значення "такий само, інший, наступний, увесь, подібний" тощо.

Інший приклад — слово *кристал*:

> [κρύσταλλος](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BA%CF%81%CF%8D%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%82) походить від слова [κρύος (krúos)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BA%CF%81%CF%8D%CE%BF%CF%82#Ancient_Greek) і споріднене з українським словом ***крига***. Плюс той самий суфікс *-αλλο-*.

---

#### Висновок

Окремо перекладати суфікси — марна робота, яка призводить до помилок при перекладі. Усе, що ми з вами реально можемо робити, це:

- з'ясувати реальне значення іноземного слова цілком у тому контексті (реченні), в якому воно вжите в оригінальному тексті;
- корінь слова (без суфіксу) може лише дати натяк — не завжди точний — до якої галузі знання чи людської діяльності належить слово;
- подивитися на подібні слова в українській мові:

  - в тому числі, ті, що містять інші суфікси або не містять ніяких;
  - в тому числі, ті, що походять від іншого кореня;
- обрати найбільш слушний відповідник.

Наприклад, суфікс `-ion` зазвичай перекладається словами з суфіксом `-ція`. Але, наприклад, одним із слушних перекладів до слова *mot**ion*** є українське слово *рух*, яке не містить суфіксів. У деяких контекстах це саме слово краще перекладати як *спроба* (без суфіксів) або *намаг**ання***.

Не існує регулярного способу перекласти навіть такий простий суфікс.

Comment: Ну чому ж, темр*ява*, світл*ява*, жадібн*ява* - вельми органічно виходить. А якщо серйозно, то дякую за хорошу відповідь, але думаю, що якісь рецепти саме для цього суфікса можна знайти.

Comment: @Yola, так, але інші слова на `-ness` перекладаються з іншими суфіксами: illness, readyness, witness, fitness, badness, redness і ще [over9000](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/words-that-end-in-ness). Про це і йдеться у відповіді.

Comment: IMHO, не варто впадати в будь-яку крайність. З 1 боку, bytebuster цілковито має рацію, що _немає жодної гарантії_, що всі англ. слова з суфіксом -xxx удасться перекласти укр. словами з суфіксом -yyy. З ін. боку, задача пошуку суфікса-відповідника може виявитися не зовсім беззмістовною, адже не виключено, що для _окремих_ англ. суфіксів таки існує укр. відповідник, що подходить хоча б у _частині_ випадків (або, ін. словами, що вдасться знайти якусь закономірність, мовляв, -xxx доречно перекладати здебільшого або як -yyy₁, або як -yyy₂, або як yyy₃ — у таких-то випадках).

Comment: +1 за все, і за те, що вказали, що `autumnal, natural, accidental, seasonal, tribal` — прикметники. Не певен щодо `pastoral`. Інколи прикметники вживають як іменники, але при цьому не обов’язково кодифікують їх як іменники.

Answer (score 1):

Це, мабуть, не найкращий варіант, але як крайній захід:

> Непоширений суфікс **-ал-** позначає осіб за їх діяльністю, а також указує на предмети і явища. Загальна кількість іменників із цим формантом становить 23 одиниці. При різних семантичних ха-рактеристиках суфікса він має лише одну наголосову в складі 8 назв істот: індивід/у/áл, мед/персон/áл, принцип/áл, провінці/áл, театр/áл, тех/персон/áл, феод/áл. У 15 одиницях – найменування предметів і явищ: ліс/о/матер/і/áл, люмін/áл, матер/і/áл, фото/матер/і/áл, хлор/áл, церемон/і/áл  його наголосові ознаки лишаються незмінними,  він перебуває під наголосом. У трьох іменниках він трапляється у складі  наголошеного  комплексного  форманта  **-онал**:  інтер/наці/онáл,  наці/онáл,  професі/онáл,  чи **-уал-** (1 слово) інтелект/уáл.
> ([Тамара Товкайло, Людмила Довбня. «Вплив морфемної структури та словотвірно-розрядних значень на акцентні ознаки формантів іншомовного походження». Філологічні науки. Мовознавство. 2, 2014. Науковий вісник Східноєвропейського національного університету імені Лесі Українки. c. 109.](http://www.esnuir.eenu.edu.ua/bitstream/123456789/5504/1/25.pdf#page=4))

Comment: Мабуть це його пряме запозичення.

Comment: @Yola, а ще є _-аль_: _госпіталь_, _горизонталь_, _діагональ_, _кришталь_, _мораль_, _пастораль_, _педаль_, _спіраль_ тощо. Мабуть, (_-аль_ чи _-ал_) залежить від часу й мови запозичення. Причому слова на _-аль_ (на відміну від слів на _-ал_) бувають і чоловічого, і жіночого родів.